# Web Scraper Using Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I have to parse only the positions and points from [this link](http://www.afl.com.au/stats/player-ratings/overall-standings#). That link has 21 listings (I don't know actually what to call them) on it[image] and each listing has 40 players on it [image] expect the last one. Now I have written a code which is like this,

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

def overall_standing():
    url_list = ["http://www.afl.com.au/afl/stats/player-ratings/overall-standings#", 
                "http://www.afl.com.au/afl/stats/player-ratings/overall-standings#page/2",
#                 "http://www.afl.com.au/afl/stats/player-ratings/overall-standings#page/3",
#                 "http://www.afl.com.au/afl/stats/player-ratings/overall-standings#page/4",
#                 "http://www.afl.com.au/afl/stats/player-ratings/overall-standings#page/5",
#                 "http://www.afl.com.au/afl/stats/player-ratings/overall-standings#page/6",
#                 "http://www.afl.com.au/afl/stats/player-ratings/overall-standings#page/7",
#                 "http://www.afl.com.au/afl/stats/player-ratings/overall-standings#page/8",
#                 "http://www.afl.com.au/afl/stats/player-ratings/overall-standings#page/9",
#                 "http://www.afl.com.au/afl/stats/player-ratings/overall-standings#page/10",
#                 "http://www.afl.com.au/afl/stats/player-ratings/overall-standings#page/11",
#                 "http://www.afl.com.au/afl/stats/player-ratings/overall-standings#page/12",
#                 "http://www.afl.com.au/afl/stats/player-ratings/overall-standings#page/13",
#                 "http://www.afl.com.au/afl/stats/player-ratings/overall-standings#page/14",
#                 "http://www.afl.com.au/afl/stats/player-ratings/overall-standings#page/15",
#                 "http://www.afl.com.au/afl/stats/player-ratings/overall-standings#page/16",
#                 "http://www.afl.com.au/afl/stats/player-ratings/overall-standings#page/17",
#                 "http://www.afl.com.au/afl/stats/player-ratings/overall-standings#page/18",
#                 "http://www.afl.com.au/afl/stats/player-ratings/overall-standings#page/19",
#                 "http://www.afl.com.au/afl/stats/player-ratings/overall-standings#page/20",
                "http://www.afl.com.au/afl/stats/player-ratings/overall-standings#page/21"]

    gDictPlayerPointsInfo = {}
    for url in url_list:
        print url
        header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
        header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
        req = urllib2.Request(url,headers=header)
        page = urllib2.urlopen(req)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
        table = soup.find("table", { "class" : "ladder zebra player-ratings" })

        lCount = 1
        for row in table.find_all("tr"):
            lPlayerName = ""
            lTeamName = ""
            lPosition = ""
            lPoint = ""
            for cell in row.find_all("td"):
                if lCount == 2:
                    lPlayerName = str(cell.get_text()).strip().upper()
                elif lCount == 3:
                    lTeamName = str(cell.get_text()).strip().split("\n")[-1].strip().upper()
                elif lCount == 4:
                    lPosition = str(cell.get_text().strip())
                elif lCount == 6:
                    lPoint = str(cell.get_text().strip())

                lCount += 1

            if url == "http://www.afl.com.au/afl/stats/player-ratings/overall-standings#page/2":
                print lTeamName, lPlayerName, lPoint
            if lPlayerName <> "" and lTeamName <> "":
                lStr = lPosition + "," + lPoint

#                 if gDictPlayerPointsInfo.has_key(lTeamName):
#                     gDictPlayerPointsInfo[lTeamName].append({lPlayerName:lStr})
#                 else:
                gDictPlayerPointsInfo[lTeamName+","+lPlayerName] = lStr
            lCount = 1


    lfp = open("a.txt","w")
    for key in gDictPlayerPointsInfo:
        if key.find("RICHMOND"):
            lfp.write(str(gDictPlayerPointsInfo[key]))

    lfp.close()
    return gDictPlayerPointsInfo


# overall_standing()
```

but the problem is it always gives me the first listing's points and positions, It ignored the other 20. How could I get the positions and points for the whole 21? Now I heard scrapy can do this type thing pretty easy but I am not fully familiar with scrapy. Is there any other way possible than using scrapy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is happening because these links are handled by the server, and often the portion of the link followed by the `#` symbol, called the [fragment identifier](http://www.w3.org/DesignIssues/Fragment.html), is processed by the browser and refers to some link or `javascript` behavior, i.e. loading a different set of results.

I would suggest two appraoches, either finding a way to use a link which the server can evaluate that you could continue using `scrapy` with or using a webdriver like `selenium`.

**Scrapy**

Your first step is to identify the `javascript` load call, often `ajax`, and use those links to pull your information.  These are calls to the site's DB.  This can be done by opening your web inspector and watching the network traffic as you click the next search result page:

[image: Before clicking]

and then after the click

[image: after clicking]

we can see that there is a new call the this url:

```
http://www.afl.com.au/api/cfs/afl/playerRatings?roundId=CD_R201401408&pageNum=3&pageSize=40
```

This url returns a `json` file which can be parsed, and you can even shorten your steps are it looks like you can control more what information is returned to you.

You could either write a method to generate a series of links for you:

```
def gen_url(page_no):
    return "http://www.afl.com.au/api/cfs/afl/playerRatings?roundId=CD_R201401408&pageNum=" + str(page_no) + "&pageSize=40"
```

and then, for example, use `scrapy` with the seed list:

```
seed = [gen_url(i) for i in range(20)]
```

or you can try tweaking the url parameters and see what you get, maybe you can get multiple pages at a time:

```
http://www.afl.com.au/api/cfs/afl/playerRatings?roundId=CD_R201401408&pageNum=1&pageSize=200
```

I changed the end the `pageSize` parameter to `200` since it seems this corresponds directly to the number of results returned.

**NOTE** There is a chance this method would not work as sites sometimes block their data API from outside usage via screening the ip of where the request is coming from.

If this is the case you should go with the following approach.

**Selenium (or other webdriver)**

Using something like [`selenium`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium) which is a webdriver, you can use what is loaded into a browser to evaluate data that is loaded after the server has returned the webpage.

There is some [initial setup](http://jimmyg.org/blog/2009/getting-started-with-selenium-and-python.html) that needs to be set up in order for selenium to be usable, but it is a very powerful tool once you have it working.

A simple example of this would be:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.afl.com.au/stats/player-ratings/overall-standings")
```

You will see a python controlled Firefox browser (this can be done with other browsers too) open on your screen and load the url you provide, then follow the commands you give it which can be done from a shell even (useful for debugging) and you can search and parse html in the same way you would with `scrapy` (code contd from previous code section...)

If you want to perform something like clicking the next page button:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='pagination']//li[@class='page']")
```

That expression may need some tweaking but it intends to find all the `li` elements of `class='page'` that are in the `div` with `class='pagination'`, the `//` means shortened path between elements, your other alternative would be like `/html/body/div/div/.....` until you get to the one in question, which is why `//div/...` is useful and appealing.

For specific help and reference on locating elements see [their page](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/locating-elements.html)

My usual method is trial and error for this, tweaking the expression until it hits the target elements I want.  This is where the console/shell comes in handy.  After setting up the `driver` as above, I usually try and build my expression:

Say you have an `html` structure like:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
             <div id="info-i-want">
                  treasure chest
             </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I would start with something like:

```
>>> print driver.get_element_by_xpath("//body")
'<body>
    <div id="container">
         <div id="info-i-want">
              treasure chest 
         </div>
    </div>
</body>'
>>> print driver.get_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='container']")
<div id="container">
     <div id="info-i-want">
          treasure chest 
     </div>
</div>
>>> print driver.get_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='info-i-want']")
<div id="info-i-want">
     treasure chest 
</div>
>>> print driver.get_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='info-i-want']/text()")
treasure chest 
>>> # BOOM TREASURE!
```

Usually it will be more complex, but this is a good and often necessary debugging tactic.

Back to your case, you could then save them out into an array:

```
links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='pagination']//li[@class='page']")
```

and then one by one click them, scrape the new data, click the next one:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

driver = None
try:
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get("http://www.afl.com.au/stats/player-ratings/overall-standings")

    #
    # Scrape the first page
    #

    links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='pagination']//li[@class='page']")

    for link in links:
        link.click()
        #
        # scrape the next page
        #
        time.sleep(1) # pause for a time period to let the data load
finally:
    if driver:
        driver.close()
```

It is best to wrap it all in a `try...finally` type block to make sure you close the driver instance.

If you decide to delve deeper into the selenium approach, you can refer to their [docs](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/index.html) which have excellent and very explicit documentation and [examples](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/getting-started.html#walk-through-of-the-example).

Happy scraping!

Comment: Very helpful and extensive answer. **+1**.