# Is it possible to pull only part of the HTML page when attempting to pull HTML Data?

Tags: python, html, json

I have pulled the HTML code from a website. But I am not sure if I have pulled it all for some reason. Can anyone help?!

```
import urllib.request
import re

#This requests the website URL
url = ('https://www.myvue.com/whats-on')

req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

def main():

        html_page = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()

        content = html_page.decode(errors='ignore', encoding='utf-8')

        #data = re.findall('<span rv-text="item.title">(.*?)</span>', content)
        #print(data)

        print(html_page)
main()
```

Comment: This website uses javascript to load additional content. Is that what you are missing?

Comment: If the site uses dynamically load the content, then yes. Try [selenium](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium)

Comment: Both the above users are correct, you need to handle the dynamically loaded content.  A while back I answered a question for a user who had a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23679334/2461379.  I spent some time trying to give a reasonably thorough guide to handling this issue.

Comment: Yes maybe that is what I'm missing. Thanks